# Creating a list using an attribute query with arcpy.da.SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor, list

I have a shapefile of a river network containing the following fields: toJunction, fromJunction, Int_DAM (which indicates free-flowing status) and Strahler. I'm trying to create a list of the rows where `Int_DAM = 'Downstream'` using arcpy.da.SearchCursor. I'm getting an error that says:

`RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.`

Here is the code as I have it:

```
Sel_list = []
fc = r"C:\Data\Free_Flowing_Rivers_Results\NHN_Canada_Stream_Order_by_Basin_160412.gdb\Datasets\NHN_HN_PrimaryDirectedNLFlow_07_Stream_Order"

fields = ['fromJunction', 'toJunction', 'Int_DAM', 'Strahler']
where_clause = '"Int_DAM"' + "=" + 'Downstream'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (fields), where_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        Sel_list.append(row)

print Sel_list
```

I've double checked the file and the fields are definitely present. I'm pretty new to Python so I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the quote marks in your `where_clause` are set up wrong.

it should say `Int_DAM = 'Downstream'` but instead it says `"Int_DAM" = Downstream`.

```
Sel_list = []
fc = r"C:\Data\Free_Flowing_Rivers_Results\NHN_Canada_Stream_Order_by_Basin_160412.gdb\Datasets\NHN_HN_PrimaryDirectedNLFlow_07_Stream_Order"

fields = ['fromJunction', 'toJunction', 'Int_DAM', 'Strahler']
where_clause = """ Int_DAM = 'Downstream' """

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, where_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        Sel_list.append(row)

print Sel_list
```

Alternatively you can use `arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters` when constructing your where clause to ensure you've set up the field names correctly.  That way you can switch between different types of database.  From [AddFieldDelimiters - Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm):

> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on the
>   format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
>   shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
>   square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
>   delimiters. The function can take away the guess work in ensuring that
>   the field delimiters used with your SQL expression are the correct
>   ones.

So your where clause would become:

```
where_clause = """ {0} = '{1}' """.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, 'Int_DAM'), 'Downstream')
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy and past this, it should work

```
where_clause = "Int_DAM="+"'Downstream'"
```

Comment: should be `where_clause` - the upper-case `W` will make this not work as the search cursor refers to `where_clause` with a lower-case `w`.  Python likes to get picky regarding case.

Comment: really? wouldn't the where_clause just be treated as a variable so in theory it shouldn't matter...

Comment: Variable names are case sensitive in python.  `Where_Clause` and `where_clause` are two different variable names.